# How to create new object on each button click in Java ee?

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-7

I'm practising Java ee and I made a two input fields and button in jsp. When clicked on button "add" I want to add those two fields in a list and just show them on my jsp page. For now it's showing me only one result each time I click on button. What am I doing wrong?

This is my jsp:

```
<body>
    <form action="addtocart" method="GET">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title"> <br>
        Price: <input type="text" name="price"> <br>
        <button type="subtmit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <c:forEach var="bookList" items="${book}"> 
        <ul>
            <li>${bookList.name}</li>
            <li>${bookList.price}</li>
        </ul>          
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

And this is my servlet:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
        ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();    
        list.add(new Book(title,price));   
        session.setAttribute("book", list);      
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: I did that, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You are creating a new `ArrayList<Book>` on every call of `doGet` and setting the same into the session. Thus, on every call of `doGet` the list is getting reset.

## Solution

Get the existing list from the session and add a book to it. Create a new list only when it is not present in the session.

```
@WebServlet("/addtocart")
public class BooklistServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
        ArrayList<Book> list = (ArrayList<Book>) session.getAttribute("book");
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        }
        list.add(new Book(title, price));
        session.setAttribute("book", list);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I recommend you display the list only when it is not empty as shown below:

```
<body>
    <form action="addtocart" method="GET">
        Title: <input type="text" name="title"> <br> Price: <input
            type="text" name="price"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <c:forEach var="bookList" items="${book}">
        <c:if test="${not empty book}">
            <ul>
                <li>${bookList.title}</li>
                <li>${bookList.price}</li>
            </ul>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

As you can see, I've added the check `<c:if test="${not empty book}">` as a condition for the visibility of the list.

Comment: He was using session storage. You are creating a shared storage over all users!

Comment: @GreyFairer - I've fixed the problem in my code. I can see that you have edited the answer by Nitin Pareek. Make sure you put the `null` check otherwise that code will throw NPE.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Hey, it works now, thank you! I just have trouble understanding this line (ArrayList<Book>) session.getAttribute("book"); How can we get attribute before we set it in session?

Comment: @NemJov - In the line, `ArrayList<Book> list = (ArrayList<Book>) session.getAttribute("book");` we are getting the object for the attribute, `book` from session. If the object is present in the session, it will be returned; otherwise, `null` will be returned. Therefore, we are checking the same with `if (list == null) { list = new ArrayList<Book>(); }` i.e. if `list` is `null`, create a new `ArrayList` and assign it to `list`. This assignment will happen only when `list == null`, otherwise `list` will have the object returned from session.

Comment: Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score -1):

Every time the statement **session.setAttribute("book", list);** runs, it replaces the previous list in the session with the new one.

You should first try to fetch the existing list and then add your current book object to it.

```
ArrayList<Book> list =(ArrayList<Book>)session.getAttribute("book");  // get the current list from the session
list.add(new Book(...));
session.setAttribute("book", list);  // store list in session
```

This should give you the output you are asking for.. Make sure you handle the **NullPointerException** that may be thrown when you add the element in the list.

Comment: Nitin - `getAttribute` will not throw NPE; rather, it will return `null` and subsequently when you call `list.add(...)`, this call will be performed on a `null` reference throwing the error. Check my answer to understand it.